# General solution of differential equation via variation of parameters

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I have found the general solution to the following differential equation: $y''+y=2\cos(x)+3e^{-x}+5$ using the method of variation of parameters but it's the first time I have used it so I would appreciate some feedback about my solution (right, wrong, can it be improved, how....?)

What I have done:

The associated homogeneous equation is: $y''+y=0$ with solution $y_o=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)$;

Using the method of variation of parameters we try to determine functions $v_1(x)$ and $v_2(x)$ such that $y_p=v_1(x)\cos(x)+v_2(x)\sin(x)$ is a particular solution of the differential equation.

We find that $v_1(x)$ and $v_2(x)$ must satisfy the following conditions:
$ (1)\ v'_1(x)\cos(x)+v'_2(x)\sin(x)=0 \\
  (2)\ -v'_1\sin(x)+v'_2\cos(x)=2\cos(x)+3e^{-x}+5
$

and applying Cramer's rule we can solve and find that

$v'_1=-\sin(x)(2\cos(x)+3e^{-x}+5)$ and $v'_2=\cos(x)(2\cos(x)+3e^{-x}+5)$ thus, by integrating, we have that $\fbox{$v_1(x)=\frac{3}{2}e^{-x}(\cos(x)+\sin(x))+5\cos(x)+\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+C_1$}$ and $\fbox{$v_2(x)=\frac{3}{2}e^{-x}(\sin(x)-\cos(x))+5\sin(x)-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+C_2$}$ thus the general solution is

$\fbox{$y_g(x)=y_o(x)+y_p(x)=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)+v_1(x)\cos(x)+v_2(x)\sin(x)$}$ where $v_1(x)$ and $v_2(x)$ are as above.

Comment: There are extraneous factors in your final answer. Plug back this solution in the initial equation to check.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for your interest in mi question: I suspected that, but my problem is that I cannot see where I went wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should start to  first solve the DE $y''+y=2\cos x$ then $y''+y=3e^{-x}$ Plus  when you use  that method  of  variation of parameters  you dont have to keep the constants of integration.

Comment: And maybe your answer is not that wrong you just need to simplify the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this DE is simple:
$$y''+y=2\cos x$$
$$\implies y_h=c_1\cos  x +c_2 \sin x$$
$$y_p=Ax \sin x$$
Your solution has too many terms. Plus the $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms are mixed with the exponential when it shouldn't be the case.
$$ y(x)=c_1\cos  x +c_2 \sin x+Ax\sin x +Be^{-x}+C$$